# Get an index of a Matrix filled with entries

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, bind, tkinter-entry

I want to make a 3x3 matrix of entries and those entries I want them to interact them each other.

I want each time when I introduce a float value and then press Enter key inside of an entry (just in the first and second column) I want that the third column show the sum of the first and second column in the row that was modified.

Like this:

```
|   0.0|   2.5|   2.5|
|   2.4|   1.5|   3.9|
|   1.1|   2.2|   3.3|
```

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

global i,j,m

def compute(master):
    suma=0.0
    for x in range (0,1):
        suma+=float(m[i][x].get())
    if not i==0:
        suma+=float(m[i-1][2].get())
    print suma
    m[i][2].insert(str(suma))


root = Tk()

alto =3
ancho=3


m = [[0 for x in range(alto)] for y in range(ancho)]



for i in range (0, alto):
    for j in range (0, ancho):
        m[i][j]= Entry(root)
        m[i][j].grid(row = i,column = j)
        m[i][j].insert(0,"0.0")
        if (j==0 or j==1):
            m[i][j].bind('<Return>', compute)
        else:
            m[i][j].config(state='readonly')

root.mainloop()
```

How I can get the index of an entry modified when I press Enter key?

I know that could be comparing a variable matrix and the current values of all entries but that could use a lot resources because next to this I will use a database with a lot of values.

Comment: `suma=0,0` should be `suma=0.0`...

Comment: Since you seem to be computing the value of all of the columns, is there a reason why you need the index of the entry? The bound function will be given an object that has a reference to the actual widget that was changed.

Comment: The reference is "master" in compare function? How you can know which widget was changed with "master"?

Comment: `master` in your code is poorly named. The canonical name is `event`, and `event.widget` is a reference to the widget that caught the event.

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have some learning to do on how to debug your code, as there are many small errors. Here is your code, with comments as to several things that you have done wrong that could have been found with some simple debugging. Please spend some time trying to figure this stuff out before posting to here.

```
from Tkinter import *

global i, j, m

# "You should rename master because that is a very misleading name. The 
#  canonical name is event, though some prefer evt." – Bryan Oakley
def compute(master):
    suma = 0.0
    # This for loop will only iterate once. You need range(0, 2): for it to go
    # through the code twice
    for x in range(0, 1):
        suma += float(m[i][x].get())

    # I can't figure out the purpoes of this
    if not i == 0:
        suma += float(m[i - 1][2].get())
    print suma

    # You've done it properly in the for loop, but not here. insert() needs an
    # index as its first parameter
    m[i][2].insert(str(suma))


root = Tk()

alto = 3
ancho = 3
m = [[0 for x in range(alto)] for y in range(ancho)]

# Because i is a global, and the below for loop, i is only ever going to
# be equal to 2, which means your compute code is only going to compute
# the 3rd row.
for i in range(0, alto):
    for j in range(0, ancho):
        m[i][j] = Entry(root)
        m[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)
        m[i][j].insert(0, "0.0")
        if (j == 0 or j == 1):
            m[i][j].bind('<Return>', compute)
        else:
            m[i][j].config(state='readonly')

root.mainloop()
```

Here is a fixed version of your compute function. Please take the time to go through and understand the changes I've made.

```
def compute(master):
    # Loop through each row in the grid
    for i in range(0, alto):
        suma = 0.0
        for x in range(0, 2):
            # I've left in the prints I've used to debug as exmaples for you
            print "i", i
            print "get", m[i][x].get()
            suma += float(m[i][x].get())
        print "suma", suma, "\n"
        # You cannot insert into a readonly entry, so set it to normal first
        m[i][2].config(state='normal')
        # Inserting every time will add the string to the beginning of the
        # entry, so that it builds up on every run. Instead delte the conetents
        # of the entry first, and then insert.
        m[i][2].delete(0, END)
        m[i][2].insert(0, str(suma))
        # Set the entry back to readonly
        m[i][2].config(state='readonly')
```

Comment: You should rename `master` because that is a very misleading name. The canonical name is `event`, though some prefer `evt`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help. I'm new in python and tkinter. I solved the problem. Special thanks to:

> Bryan Oakley and Jordan Gleeson

Here is the solution:

```
from Tkinter import *

global m

def indexes(event):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            if event.widget == m[i][j]:
                return i,j

def compute(event):
    i,j = indexes(event)

    suma=0.0
    for x in range (0,2):
        suma+=float(m[i][x].get())

    m[i][2].config(state='normal')
    m[i][2].delete(0, END)
    m[i][2].insert(0,str(suma))
    m[i][2].config(state='readonly')



root = Tk()

alto =3
ancho=3

sv = [[0 for x in range(alto)] for y in range(ancho)]
m = [[0 for x in range(alto)] for y in range(ancho)]

for i in range (0, alto):
    for j in range (0, ancho):
        #sv [i] [j] = StringVar()
        #sv[i][j] = "0.0"
        m[i][j]= Entry(root)#, textvariable=sv [i] [j])
        m[i][j].grid(row = i,column = j)
        m[i][j].insert(0,"0.0")
        if (j==0 or j==1):
            m[i][j].bind('<Return>', compute)
        else:
            m[i][j].config(state='readonly')   

root.mainloop()
```